# Determine if software is installed and what version on Mac in Node.js JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, plist, photoshop

I am in a node environment on Mac within a Electron application and I am needing to:

1. test if Photoshop is installed
2. get version of installed Photoshop
3. launch Photoshop

This was all extremely easy to do in windows. I branch on nodejs os modules platform method so if 'Darwin' I need to do the above things.

I am not a Mac user so I do not know much about the processes on Mac.

I can parse `.plist` files if need be but poking around users lib preference folder hasn't showed up much. There are Photoshop specific `.psp` preference files but I have no way to see whats inside them and merely checking to see if there is a Photoshop file located in folder seems way to sloppy to me plus I need to get the version.

## Solution

*After some research I came across the **mac** system profiler utility which seems to exist on all **mac** operating systems.*

using `node`'s `exec` module I get all installed applications and some details about each that look like

> TextEdit:
>
> ```
>  Version: 1.13
>  Obtained from: Apple
>  Last Modified: 6/29/18, 11:19 AM
>  Kind: Intel
>  64-Bit (Intel): Yes
>  Signed by: Software Signing, Apple Code Signing Certification Authority, Apple Root CA
>  Location: /Applications/TextEdit.app
> ```

now I just needed to write a simple parser to parse the results which were large with over 335 applications into json for easy querying.

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';

let proc = exec( 'system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType -detailLevel mini' );
let results = '';
proc.stdout.on( 'data', ( data ) => { results += `${ data }`; } );
proc.on( 'close', async ( code ) =>
{
    let parsed = await this.sysProfileTxtToJson( results );
} );
```

the `sysProfileTxtToJson` is my little parsing method

now `parsed` is a json object that I query to determine if photoshop is installed and if multiple version which is the latest version.

here is the parsing method of which needs improved

```
sysProfileTxtToJson ( data: string )
{
    return new Promise<any>( ( res ) =>
    {
        let stream = new Readable();
        stream.push( data );
        stream.push( null );

        let lineReader = createInterface( stream );
        let apps = { Applications: [] };
        let lastEntry = '';
        let appPrefix = '    ';
        let appPropertyPrefix = '      ';
        let lastToggle, props = false;
        lineReader.on( 'line', ( line: string ) =>
        {
            if ( line == '' && !lastToggle )
            {
                props = false;
                return;
            }

            if ( line.startsWith( appPrefix ) && !props )
            {
                lastEntry = line.trim().replace( ':', '' );
                lastToggle = true;
                let current = {};
                current[ "ApplicationName" ] = lastEntry
                apps.Applications.push( current );
                props = true;
                return;
            }

            if ( line.startsWith( appPropertyPrefix ) && props )
            {
                lastToggle = false;
                let tokens = line.trim().split( ':' );
                let last = apps.Applications[ apps.Applications.length - 1 ];
                last[ tokens[ 0 ] ] = tokens[ 1 ].trim();
            }
        } );

        lineReader.on( 'close', () =>
        {
            res( apps );
        } );
    } );
}
```

Comment: How do you detect if user has installed photoshop on windows?

Comment: how did u do this in windows..please help

Answer (score 2):

There are several features in AppleScript which can be utilized to achieve your requirement. Consider *shelling out* the necessary AppleScript/[`osascript`](https://ss64.com/osx/osascript.html) commands via nodejs.

---

Let's firstly take a look at the pertinent AppleScript commands...

#### AppleScript snippets:

1. The following AppleScript snippet returns the name of whichever version of Photoshop is installed (E.g. `Photoshop CS5`, `Photoshop CS6`, `Photoshop CC`, etc ...). We'll need the name to be able to successfully launch the application.

   ```c
    tell application "Finder" to get displayed name of application file id "com.adobe.Photoshop"
   ```

   Note: The snippet above errors if Photoshop is *not* installed, so we can also utilize this to determine if the application is installed or not.
2. The following snippet obtains whichever version of Photoshop is installed:

   ```c
    tell application "Finder" to get version of application file id "com.adobe.Photoshop"
   ```

   This returns a long String indicating [the version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop_version_history). It will be something like this fictitious example:

   > `19.0.1 (19.0.1x20180407 [20180407.r.1265 2018/04/12:00:00:00) © 1990-2018 Adobe Systems Incorporated`

---

#### Launching Photoshop:

After it has been inferred that PhotoShop is installed consider utilizing Bash's [`open`](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html) command to launch the application. For instance:

```bash
open -a "Adobe Photoshop CC"
```

---

#### Example node application:

The following gist demonstrates how the aforementioned commands can be utilized in node.

Note: The gist below is utilizing [`shelljs`](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs)'s [`exec`](http://documentup.com/shelljs/shelljs#execcommand--options--callback) command to execute the AppleScript/osascript commands. However you could utilize nodes builtin [`child_process.execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) or [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) instead.

```js
const os = require('os');
const { exec } = require('shelljs');

const APP_REF = 'com.adobe.Photoshop';
const isMacOs = os.platform() === 'darwin';

/**
 * Helper function to shell out various commands.
 * @returns {String} The result of the cmd minus the newline character.
 */
function shellOut(cmd) {
  return exec(cmd, { silent: true }).stdout.replace(/\n$/, '');
}


if (isMacOs) {

  const appName = shellOut(`osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" \
      to get displayed name of application file id "${APP_REF}"'`);

  if (appName) {
    const version = shellOut(`osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" \
        to get version of application file id "${APP_REF}"'`).split(' ')[0];

    console.log(version); // Log the version to console.

    shellOut(`open -a "${appName}"`); // Launch the application.
  } else {
    console.log('Photoshop is not installed');
  }
}
```

Comment: Wonderfull ideas @RobC . I ended up using the *Mac* system profiler command line utility. I use *node* `exec('system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType -detailLevel mini')` to get the list of all applications installed then wrote a simple parser that parsed the results into javascript objects so I could then query the resulting array easily. The profiler returns the application version as well the `*.app` path of which I can use to launch. I do not know anything about applescript but the solutions provided seem like a viable option I just went with `exec` as no additional deps are needed.